# photoshop selection dragging during creation of a shape

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to drag a selection and move it around while you create it? I know there's a program that supports this but I don't remember which.
like some sort of a key combo.
for example holding shift while sizing you shape keeps the aspect ratio and holding alt duplicates your sizing in the opposite direction. I would think that holding ctrl would let me move the shape around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure is.

Hold the **Space Bar** down while you are dragging out a selection.

This works with the Rectangular Marquee, Elliptical Marquee, Single Line Marquees, and all the Shape tools.

Comment: Thanks! I remembered there was such a functionality but I couldn't recall where.

Comment: I also just realized you've answered another question I had before. you seem like a very active user here so I wanted to thank you for that as well.

Comment: Glad I could help :)